# Canvas to draw polygon over mapview in Android

Tags: android, canvas, android-mapview, android-maps

I need to draw a Polygon from several points (I have their latitude, longitude). 
I am basing my implementation from these two answers: 
[Drawing an empty polygon given a set of points on a Map Overylay (Android 2.1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2815080/drawing-an-empty-polygon-given-a-set-of-points-on-a-map-overylay-android-2-1)
[Drawing a line/path on Google Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176397/drawing-a-line-path-on-google-maps)

In my MapOverlayAction.java I set the overlay for some pins like this:

```
mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);
setLocationOverlay(mapView, mapController);
```

where itemizedoverlay is an array of OverlayItems

This works fine. But I also need to draw a polygon for these points (where each point is a vertex). So what I do is:

```
Path path = new Path();

 for (int j = 0; j < itemizedoverlay.size(); j++) {

   GeoPoint gP1 = itemizedoverlay.getItem(j).getPoint();
   Point currentScreenPoint = new Point();

    Projection projection = mapView.getProjection();
    projection.toPixels(gP1, currentScreenPoint);

    if (j == 0)
      path.moveTo(currentScreenPoint.x, currentScreenPoint.y); 
    else
      path.lineTo(currentScreenPoint.x, currentScreenPoint.y);
}
```

In both of the answersI am basing my solution, the following method is being called:

```
    Paint   mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setDither(true);
    mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
    mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(2);    

    canvas.drawPath(path, mPaint);
```

My question is, where do I get that canvas from?
I have all this code in my activity class.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to subclass the Overlay class and override the [Draw](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/Overlay.html#draw%28android.graphics.Canvas,%20com.google.android.maps.MapView,%20boolean%29) method to get your canvas.

then instantiate your new class and add it to the list of Overlays to have it appear on the map. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176397/drawing-a-line-path-on-google-maps) should help.

Comment: Thanks, I am using that question on my solution as I quoted in my question. Anyways, now I tried exactly as the answer there says (and as you said it should be done and it works) I just thought it could be done some other way. Thanks