# How to plot Offline map and on map Plot marker from database

Tags: android, gps

I am trying to make a android application that display a map when application run without using any internet connection ie. offline map show.On map i want to plot some latitude and longitude that are stored in my database.Basically i want plot a offline map and on map  i need to display some marker from my database.But i could not plot offline map and marker.I searched more on Google but i could not found any better solution.

Can any one help me how can i plot map offline.
thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use GeoPoint lat-lon, convert it into a point (x,y) (co-ordinate geometry), and use canvas to draw the line/shape you want. Eg.:

GeoPoint gp = new GeoPoint((int)(lat * 1E6), (int)(lon * 1E6));

and for drawing using the canvas, refer to:
 [How to draw filled polygon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047573/how-to-draw-filled-polygon)

Also,
[Drawing an empty polygon given a set of points on a Map Overylay (Android 2.1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2815080/drawing-an-empty-polygon-given-a-set-of-points-on-a-map-overylay-android-2-1)

Comment: Sir,firstly i could not plot an offline map so please help for plotting offline map.

Comment: start with running the app without internet application and take static lat, lon co-ordinates. Can you see the map right now?(without location identifiers etc) Check the links above and start with a line between a lat,lon pairs